# SOQL Get child with most rows grouped by parent

Tags: soql, aggregate, count

Let's say i have the following structure

Object Car is a parent of many (object) Incidents that are also children of an Area

So the table of incidents looks like this

INCIDENTS

```
 ID   CAR   AREA 

 1    A      AREA1
 2    B      AREA2
 3    B      AREA1
 4    B      AREA2
 5    C      AREA1
```

.... and so on

What i need is, for each CAR, get the AREA where the most incidents happened.

RESULT SHOULD BE

```
CAR  AREA
  A   AREA1
  B   AREA2 //because for car b the area with the most incidents was AREA2 (2 times)
  C   AREA1
```

For the life of me i cant figure out how to do it. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you add a larger (and clearer) data sample from which to extrapolate what you are trying to query? As written, Your second table uses different values for `CAR` than the first, and there are so few values it becomes difficult to interpret.

Comment: The different type of values was by mistake. Basically i want to count which AREA from the INCIDENTS table appeared the most times, BUT for each car. So for car A we got only 1 incident in AREA1, that is the max. For car B, there are 3 incidents, 2 of them in area2 and 1 in AREA1, so the max count record is AREA2

Answer (score 0):

You can include all results ordered by child count, then filter via post processing.

```
SELECT Car__c, Area__c, count(Id) FROM MyObject__c
GROUP BY Car__c, Area__c ORDER BY count(Id) DESC
```

The results would look like:

```
CAR    AREA     count(Id)
========================
B      AREA2    2
A      AREA1    1
B      AREA1    1
C      AREA1    1
```

Then, you can just iterate the results and store only the first one you observe:

```
Map<String, AggregateResult> results = new Map<String, AggregateResult>();
for (AggregateResult result : [/*above query*/])
{
    String car = (String)result.get('Car__c');
    if (!results.containsKey(car))
    {
        results.put(car, result);
    }
}
```

Or if you wanted just the `AREA`, you could do `Map<String, String>` and get the value using a similar approach to how you got the key.

Comment: Or, sort ASC, and just put each value in the map; the higher value will bump the lower value out of the same key. It's marginally faster to avoid containsKey if you can help it.

Comment: Hmm, I would have assumed the converse. That said, if you run into CPU limits for this use case it would be surprising.